# Eloquent count of single object is wrong

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a method that only changes one small thing based on if an object of one item is passed through, vs a single object, but the count() is wrong on single items...

Assuming I have 25 entries in my table...

```
$contacts = Contact::all();
dd("Count = " . $contacts->count());
```

> Count = 25

```
$contact = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->first();
dd("Count = " . $contact->count());
```

> Count = 25

Why is it showing a count of objects in the table instead of just the number that were returned?

- Laravel v9.19
- PHP v8.0.2

Comment: FYI I know this isn't using standard db naming convention (using individual_id instead of id) but that's the database I have to work with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your code:

```
$contact = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->first();
```

`$contact` will either be an instance of your `Contact` model, or `null`.

If it is a Model instance, then calling `->count()` is basically calling this:

```
Contact::count(); // 25

$contact = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->first();
$contact->count() == Contact::count(); // true
```

Models have a `count()` method, so you can do things like `$model->where(...)->count()`, etc.

If `$contact` is `null`, then your code will fail:

```
$contact = null;
$contact->count(); // Error: `null->count()` is invalid.
```

So, for your case, there is basically no reason to ever call `Contact::where(...)->first()->count()`, as that will not return `1`, unless there is legitimately 1 record in your `contacts` table (pretty scary false-positive).

The other answer suggests to use `->get()`, which is valid, as a `Collection` has a `count()` method that outputs the length of the underlying Array:

```
$contact = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->get();
$contact->count(); // 1
```

It will return 1, unless you have multiple records in the database where `individual_id` is equal to `$id`.

So, TL;DR: `->first()` returns a single `Contact` instance or `null` and shouldn't use `->count()` after, while `::all()` or `->get()` returns multiple and can use `->count()` after.

Comment: So basically I need to rethink how I'm doing this, as, if I do `->get()`, it returns an array of objects, which breaks the other parts of the code. So in this method I'm working with, I just need to pass along if the object is a single instance instead of relying on `->count()`.

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time to explain in detail.

Comment: Basically, yes. `->first()` should be used if you're expecting (or only need) a single Model instance. `->get()` will always return a `Collection`, which can contain 0-∞ Model instances. And no problem! The other answer suggests something, but doesn't really explain _why_; I figured I would help make it clearer what is happening.

Comment: Also, there's PHP's `count()` method, which in this case would return `1`: `dd("Count: " . count($contact));`, but also raises a warning re: `count()` should use an array or object that implements `countable`, which Models apparently don't. But again, it just depends on your use case 

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and got the error, and `->toArray()` gave me `5` for some reason :D

Comment: Your `Contact` model has 5 properties (from the columns of your `contacts` table), so `Contact::first()->toArray()` produces something like `['id' => 1, 'name' => 'whatever', ...]`, and `count([...])` counts the length of the resulting array 

Comment: I did a loop and var_dump of $contact->toArray() and got:
```
^ 5
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Anyway, I was just working too hard to make a solution a little more elegant. At some point you just give in and pass the count manually, so the singles just pass `1`, and the array of objects I pass in `$contacts->count()`. Thanks for the help and explanations!

Comment: No need to loop; just `dd(Contact::all()->toArray())`, or `dd(Contact::where(...)->first()->toArray())`; ; not sure how you got those `bool`s. But yeah, whatever approach works for you is good, as long as it's somewhat efficient and consistent. Happy to provide the explanations though, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using first() it is returning MODEL.You have to use get() so that you can use count() as get() will return collection.

```
$contact = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->get();
dd("Count = " . $contact->count());
```

It will give you the desired result.

also you can do this...

```
$count = Contact::where('individual_id', '=', $id)->count();
dd("Count = " . $count);
```